# Altering elements that are loaded from buttons after the page itself is finished loading

Tags: javascript, html

I realize the title is a bit unclear, so I'll elaborate as well as possible. Essentially, there is a webpage that the user visits. After the page completes its initial load, the user may then click a button on the page which will load new content into the page. Something like `<div class="expanded" style>` -- basically a bunch of text and perhaps some links.

I essentially need to alter the contents of this newly loaded area. Right now, I am running something like:

```
$('div.expand-button').click(function(){ //When the button to load new content is clicked...
```

And then fire off my `document.querySelectorAll` function at this point. However, if I do this, the new content is not finished loading when the function runs, and, as a result, nothing happens. What's the best way of delaying my function so that it will only run after the new content area is loaded?

Comment: I dont know if I am fully following what you were trying to say so forgive me if I am wrong. It seems like you have dynamic content that is loaded based on some sort of user interaction (such as a click). When this new content is loaded you want to have a click function for the newly loaded content? If so you need to use the jQuery on event to bind dynamically built elements.

Comment: Sorry - I edited to make it a bit clearer. I already have a click function for the button that loads this new content, but it fires before the content itself is loaded. So, I need to find a way of running my function after the new content is completely loaded rather than too early, as it currently is. This is essentially what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you place that new content, e.g. do you use $.ajax or $().load?

Comment: Unfortunately, the website is not my own. This is intended for use as a Chrome extension, and so it's tough for me to say exactly how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and the simplest solution I found (albeit probably not the best) was to use setTimeOut. So your code would look something like :

```
$('div.expand-button').click(function(){ 
YourLoadNewAreaFunction();
setTimeout(function() {
            //do stuff you needed the page completely loaded to do
        }, 1000);
}
```

1000 is of course an arbitrary number of milliseconds I chose, you could choose whatever time you  deem necessary to completely load your new area. Assuming your new content loads in under a second, the above should work.

From what I've seen online, you could also try looking into callbacks.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling I might have to end up doing this. I figured it's possible for there to be options such as window.onLoad and whatnot, but if there aren't, I'll look into this. Thanks!